# How to assign a new var based on a disabled/enabled button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

Let's say I have a button that is disabled when the condition is false (opacity: 0.3), and enabled when the condition is true (opacity: 1).

Let's forget about the actual condition for now -- I would like to actually check when the button is disabled (opacity: 0.3) and assign a value to a new variable based on that.

For example,
if the button is disabled (opacity: 0.3), then newVar = false.
if the button is enabled (opacity: 1), then newVar = true.

How can I achieve that? Below is the code of my current button

```
<NextBtn
    orange
    withIcon
    iconStyle={{ width: '9px', height: 'auto' }}
    icon={t.image.icon.bottomChevron_orange}
    event={() => checkForError('next')}
    className="buttonNextClass"
    style={
        checkEmptyField() === true
        ? { opacity: 0.3, pointerEvents: 'none' }
        : { opacity: 1 }
    }
    >
    {c('form.content.next')}
</NextBtn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by creating a setter to set the value of `newVar`:

```
const setNewVar = (param)=>{
 newVar = param;
}
<NextBtn
    orange
    withIcon
    iconStyle={{ width: '9px', height: 'auto' }}
    icon={t.image.icon.bottomChevron_orange}
    event={() => checkForError('next')}
    className="buttonNextClass"
    style={
        checkEmptyField() === true
        ? setNewVar(false) && { opacity: 0.3, pointerEvents: 'none' }
        : setNewVar(true) &&  { opacity: 1 }
    }
    >
    {c('form.content.next')}
</NextBtn>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I keep getting this error though: "''setNewVar' is not defined  no-undef", wouldn't defining the var erase the purpose of the setter method?

Comment: Is `newVar` state or just some variable?

Comment: I mean, it doesn't really matter... I just need a variable/const/whatever that will indicate whether the button is enabled or disabled.. not sure how to go about that

Comment: You can simply write a `setter` for that. i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks bro, still not working tho, now I get a syntax error on the first line (should it be lik e this?  `(param) => {` ), and even with the corrected syntax then I get `newVar' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: @Deborah sorry for minor syntax error. i updated the answer.